Wrong definition og mathematical induction
I was reading the wikipedia's article on mathematical induction:
It has the following paragraph:

A proof by induction consists of two cases. The first, the base case, proves the statement for n = 0 without assuming any knowledge of other cases. The second case, the induction step, proves that if the statement holds for any given case n=k then it must also hold for the next case n = k +1

My issue if with the following: [...]The second case, the induction step, proves that if the statement holds for any given case n=k then it must also hold for the next case n = k. +1
It's basically saying $\forall n:P(n)$ which is what we are trying to prove, but i know that the induction step is $\forall n: P(n) \implies P(n+1)$.
Maybe my misunderstanding has something to do with the fact that english is not my first language but I interpret any with the meaning of all

No, what it’s saying is “$\forall k \geq 1$, if $P(k)$, then $P(k+1)$.” That together with $P(1)$ establishes $P(n)$ for all $n \in {\textbf N}^+$.

You have shown $P(0)$ at the start and $P(k) \implies P(k+1)$ so these together imply $P(1)$, and that implies $P(2)$, and that implies $P(3)$, and so on.  Induction allows you to state $P(0)$  combined with  $P(k) \implies P(k+1)$ implies $P(n)$ for all natural numbers $n$.

"if the statement holds for any given case n=k then ....". It sounds like you missed the "if, then" in the Wikipedia sentence.

I would use "a" rather than "any" to be clearer, but I wouldn't say the Wikipedia page is wrong, just a little bit ambiguous.
